# Matlab: changing the axis

Tags: image, matlab, plot

How can you rescale the range of the axis without changing what's on the plot itself? So I would like to keep the plot, but changing the values on the axis... Thanks for your help!

Comment: See [XTick,YTick,ZTick Here.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html)  It is near the bottom as the properties are listed in alphabetical order.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to shrink the whole picture along with the axes (changes scale?) Change axis tick labels?

Comment: I don't want to shrink the picture, just the values on the two axis

Comment: To be specific, I've got a 512x512 matrix which represents [0,1]x[0,1]. The values in the 'big' matrix are some sort of color measure. So when I plot this matrix (and using a colormap) I get a figure where both the axis go from 0 tot 512. The thing is, I want two axis going from 0 to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the specific case you mention in the comments: instead of using something like

```
imagesc(X)
```

use

```
x = linspace(0,1,size(X,1));
y = linspace(0,1,size(X,2));
imagesc(x,y,X)
```

This changes the axis scale, and the axis labels are set correspondingly.

---

In general, to change tick labels of axes, use

```
set(gca,'xtick',[10 20]) %// values where you want the labels placed
set(gca,'xticklabel',{'label1','label2'}) %// desired labels
```